# Analytical approach of representation theory

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory

I'm doing M.Sc. in mathematics. I want to do my M.Sc. thesis on Representation theory in analytic approach. So I start reading the book Representations of Finite 
and Compact Groups by Barry Simon. But it is quit difficult for me. Please give me some suggestions what are the other books I can read? What are the open problems in that field? Is it a good topic for doing M.Sc. thesis?

Comment: Do you not have an advisor/supervisor? These are questions s/he should help you with.

Comment: yes I have an supervisor but now he is too busy with his phd students @SimonS

Comment: Is it not a valid question for this site?

Comment: It is. But I guess no one has answered because it is quite an expert question with high stakes for you as a student. If I were you, I would insist that your supervisor give you guidance. It is their job and I can't think of anything more important in their supervision than helping set you off in the right direction at the start of your degree.

Comment: But at least someone can suggest me some books !!